# sending multiple bytes of data from pc serial port to custom hardware using matlab

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I am using the following matlab program to send multiple serial port data through the PC using a USB-serial port

```
close all; clear all; clc;

array_1st = ones(64, 1, 'uint8'); 
array_1st = array_1st';
for i=1:64
    array_1st(i) = array_1st(i) * i ;
end

dummy_var = zeros(1,1);

if ~isempty(instrfind)
    fclose(instrfind);
    delete(instrfind);
end

s=serial('COM9');
set(s,'Terminator','CR','DataBits',8,'Parity','none','StopBits',1,'baudrate', 38400);

fopen(s);
disp('fopen(s)');

fwrite(s, array_1st);
pause(0.5);
dummy_var = fread(s, 1);

dummy_var

fclose(s);
clear s
```

A custom hardware is connected to the serial port. I have already been able to read multiple bytes of data sent by the custom hardware in the PC using a similar matlab program (that is, multiple byte transfer from hardware -> PC through serial port using matlab is working)

I am expecting the code above to write an array of 8-bit unsigned ints when the `fwrite(s, array_1st);` function is executed. The custom hardware at this point displays the bytes received in the serial port in it's IDE's terminal and waits in a breakpoint before `dummy_var = fread(s, 1);` in the matlab program is called

The problem is matlab is always sending only the first byte of the `array_1st` array to the serial port hardware. I have tried all kinds of variations in the above program, such as removing the `array_1st = array_1st';` line, using `char` instead of `uint8`, usinf `LF` for `terminator` property in the serial port object, but the problem is always same: only the first bte of the array being sent actually goes through the serial port hardware to the custom device.

After calling `fwrite(s, array_1st);`, matlab also the following warning:

> Warning: The specified amount of data was not returned within the
>   Timeout period.

The properties of the serial object after the `fopen()`:

```
   Serial Port Object : Serial-COM9

   Communication Settings 
      Port:               COM9
      BaudRate:           38400
      Terminator:         'CR'

   Communication State 
      Status:             open
      RecordStatus:       off

   Read/Write State  
      TransferStatus:     idle
      BytesAvailable:     0
      ValuesReceived:     0
      ValuesSent:         0
```

It's properties after executing the `dummy_var = fread(s, 1);` line are:

```
   Serial Port Object : Serial-COM9

   Communication Settings 
      Port:               COM9
      BaudRate:           38400
      Terminator:         'CR'

   Communication State 
      Status:             open
      RecordStatus:       off

   Read/Write State  
      TransferStatus:     idle
      BytesAvailable:     0
      ValuesReceived:     0
      ValuesSent:         64
```

The `ValuesSent` property has been updated to 64 from 0, which I guess is indicating that, at least as far as the matlab serial port object is concerned, 64 data are being sent, but for some reason only the 1st one is actually going through the serial port hardware

What could be the reason for this? Is it that matlab just doesn't support what I want to do? If only 1 data is getting sent through the serial port hardware, why does `ValuesSent` show 64?

Matlab version is R2009b

EDIT 1: -----

I recorded the serial object data using the serial/record function, and here is what it recorded:

```
Legend: 
  * - An event occurred.
  > - A write operation occurred.
  < - A read operation occurred.

1      Recording on 29-Jul-2018 at 23:27:19.241. Binary data in little endian format.
2      > 64 uchar values.
       01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 
       11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 20 
       21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f 30 
       31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f 40 

3      < 0 uchar values.

4        Recording off.
```